# keep window hidden until init completes

Tags: javascript, electron

I am creating an window with a significant initialization process and I would like to keep the window hidden until init finishes. Right now at the beginning of my js code I hide the window right after it is created and then show it when init is complete. But this creates a less than pleasing flash when the app is launched as the window appears, disappears and then re-appears.

Is there a way to keep the window invisible while the init runs?

Comment: If the localisation process takes a bit of time then it would be better to show the window with a spinning wait icon. This way the user knows that there is something happening.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess, without seeing your code, is that you need to hide the application window using CSS in the head section of your page. This way it is hidden before the browser ever renders the page. Trying to hide the window with Javascript won't work as nicely. That's because the script can't hide the window until after the browser creates it. So, depending on conditions, the user might see it flash on start.

The snippet below shows how to do this using the CSS visibility attribute. Alternatively, you may also use the display attribute.

**Show and then run the snippet to try.**

```js
setTimeout(function() {

  // some long init process here

  // make visible on ready
  window.spinner.style.display = 'none';
  window.app.style.visibility = 'visible';
}, 3000);
```

```css
#app {
  height: 10em;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
#spinner {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<h3>Header</h3>
<div id="content">
  <img id="spinner" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOnzy.gif">
  <div id="app">APPLICATION READY</div>
</div>
<h4>footer</h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @jeff about providing some sort of progress indicator. However, the standard way to create a window that's hidden by default in Electron is to use the `show` option when creating the browser window:

```
const myWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false });
```

Then when loading/processing is finished you can make the window visible:

```
// this code runs in the renderer process
import { remote } from 'electron';

remote.getCurrentWindow().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide it first with CSS. display: none or visibility:hidden.

Then show with javascript by changing display or visibility after init.

Comment: up voted as this is the correct answer ... and 2 minutes before mine. :)

Comment: @Roberto Thanks, Looks like you have taken your time to explain and code, nice :P